# Remove scrolling glow effect/arrows

Tags: android, listview, scroll

When you  try to overscroll android scrolling views there is a glow effect appears. It's blue on ICS and above. I need to make it green. I've read a lot of topics and noticed that there is no easy solution to change this glow effect color so I've decided to completly remove this effect. This could be done by setting overScrollMode=never. But minSdkVersion must be 9 while I have it 8.

Answer (score 0):

To remove glow effect from scrollview, I've created my custom class (extends ScrollView) f and override two methods:

```
@Override
protected float getTopFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return 0.0f;
}

@Override
protected float getBottomFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: I need it to work with ViewPager, WebView, ListView etc. There're also horizontal overscroll effects. Also I'm using pull to refresh library so maybe there is a simplier solution?

Answer (score 0):

I created a method to solve this problem. It's not perfect, but it really works. You can give it a try.
Here's my code:

```
private void removeViewPagerGlowEffect(final ViewPager viewpager, final Context context) {
    viewpager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            viewpager.onTouchEvent(event);
            try {
                Field leftEdge = viewpager.getClass().getDeclaredField("mLeftEdge");
                leftEdge.setAccessible(true);
                EdgeEffectCompat effectObject = new EdgeEffectCompat(context);
                effectObject.setSize(0, 0);
                leftEdge.set(viewpager, effectObject);

                Field rightEdge = viewpager.getClass().getDeclaredField("mRightEdge");
                rightEdge.setAccessible(true);
                leftEdge.set(viewpager, effectObject);
                rightEdge.set(viewpager, effectObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```